# how to convert 5 digits number to date in python

Tags: python

I would like to convert 44562 int64 data type (5 digits number) to date format like this 1/1/2022.

```
Out[5]: 
0    44562
1    44562
2    44563
3    44563
4    44564
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

I try with

```
df['Date'].apply(lambda x: (datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0) + timedelta(int(x))).strftime("%m-%d-%Y"))
```

but output date is not correct. Please help to fix the issue.

```
Out[13]: 
0    01-03-2092
1    01-03-2092
2    01-04-2092
3    01-04-2092
4    01-05-2092
Name: Date2, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You very nearly had it:

```
df['Date'].apply(lambda x: (datetime(1899, 12, 30) + timedelta(days=int(x))).strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
```

Comment: I got the correct output with this code. can you explain the meaning of datetime(1899, 12, 30)?

Comment: @ThetPaingHmoo that date is the starting date used by Excel. Interesting blog post about that: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2006/06/16/my-first-billg-review/